# In SQL Server, how do I select IDs where value is in list, then insert matching IDs into join table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to connect a `select` and an `insert` in Query Manager

How can the two queries be tied together so that the `insert` happens for each match?

How can we call the results to verify that matching record IDs were inserted, and non-matching list items were not?

```
SELECT table1.ID  
FROM    table1  
WHERE table1.Name IN  ('Anne', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dave')  

INSERT INTO joinTable  
    (joinTable.table1_fk, joinTable.table2_fk)  
VALUES (table1.ID,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q. How can the two queries be tied together so that the insert happens for each match?

A. To move data into an existing table as a result of a query, an INSERT INTO statement does the trick.

```
INSERT INTO joinTable ('table1_fk', 'table2_fk')
SELECT ID, 1
FROM table1 
WHERE Name IN ('Anne', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dave')
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Q. How can we call the results to verify that matching record ids were inserted, and non-matching list items were not?

A. This is a single table SQL query...only those records that match the WHERE clause can be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to use `insert . . . select`.

```
INSERT INTO joinTable(table1_fk, table2_fk)  
    SELECT table1.ID, 1
    FROM    table1  
    WHERE table1.Name IN  ('Anne', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'Dave')
```